# How to add file writing feature while project is running in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

**.NET CORE , VISUAL STUDIO**

How to add file writing feature while project is running ?

When i run the project, all files will be read-only during project is running.

**I get this error.**

- Changes are not allowed while code is running

**SOLVED**

I solved that : I have included the test project ( with unit nuget packages ).

And these features are blocking writable when project is running as debug mode.

I unload the test project and it is solved.

Comment: I guess you mean with 'project is running' that the debugger is attached? In this case pause the debugger and you can edit the files again.

Comment: Yes, i mean that. I solved that : I have included the test project ( with unit nuget packages ). And these features are blocking writable when project is running as debug mode. I unload the test project and it is solved.